# How can I migrate my website into a content management system

Tags: content-management-system, dreamweaver

I have designed a website for my brother's company using Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.

How can I create a content management system (CMS) for him to let him easy to edit or post news in his website? I think that using Dreamweaver will be difficult for him.

Comment: How is your brother's existing website being served? Does he have an existing website? What operational considerations are there? How many people will have to have access to update content in the CMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any CMS is going to require server-side scripting. Typically one starts with a CMS framework, and then designs the theme around it. There is no easy way to "CMSify" your Dreamweaver design. I suggest you take a look at the [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/) framework, which will require a PHP backend. Here is a [link to a tutorial](http://jonathanwold.com/tutorials/wordpress_theme/) on creating custom Wordpress themes.

Comment: but my brother need full website to host on his company server. so if I use wordpress so I can't have full website for him.

Comment: I am talking about wordpress.org, not wordpress.com.
Check the link I provided. Wordpress.org is a CMS framework, Wordpress.com is something else entirely. Wordpress.org is something you download, and you can host it where ever you'd like.

Comment: No problem. Please accept my answer or at least up-vote it if it helped you out :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not an easy task if you don't have any experience with scripting, but depending of the complexity of the website there are some good options. What I mean is, depending on how much dynamic the site will be. Put yourself some questions like:

Is the website mostly static, and only some text areas and images have to be updated? Or are there more dynamic parts that involve the creation of new pages, like a blog or a "products" page? Do you need a friendly backend, or would your brother be ok with updating text in text files? Will it be only your brother updating the content, of he will need to manage several users?

The degree of difficulty for you will be proportional to the degree of friendliness of updating to your brother/users.

Depending on the answers to those questions you can use something has:

- as a file based CMS without interface (Kirby) or with (Monstra,
  razorCMS)
- A very simple to convert but also very basic CMS (Surreal,    Cushy,
  Perch)
- A full blown CMS that will take longer to learn, but    give
  all the flexibility to do whatever you want (there
  are many choices, but Processwire is my absolute favourite)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating a CMS, try installing an existing one that will import your static pages and perform the main steps of making them work in the new system. It's not that hard to do from scratch, but many web hosts will have some of these systems pre-installed. You can find out what CMSs your web host offers, and then Google "[name of CMS] import html".

The MODX CMS ([modx.com](http://modx.com)) has some decent tools for importing HTML into the system. Detailed instructions [here](http://www.webhostinghub.com/help/learn/modx/beginning-modx/how-import-html-modx).

WordPress has various plugins you can install to do the same thing, including [HTML Import 2](http://wordpress.org/plugins/import-html-pages/). Detailed instructions [here](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/import-static-wordpress-50653.html).

WordPress works best for people who like a simpler interface. MODX works best for people who like design control, and also for people who plan on doing a lot of their own code to extend the system.